# Graph Theory number of handshakes of couples

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

This is an Olympiad question which I now know the answer to, but I am a bit unsatisfied with it. So maybe someone can shed some light:

> **Question:** $5$ couples go to a party. Each person shakes the hand of a person they don't know. Then, Kevin asks how many hands each person shook. He gets all digits from $0$ to $8$ inclusive. How many hands did Kevin shake?
>
> **Solution:** So since person $A$ shook $8$ hands, his spouse ($B$) is the person that didn't shake any, so $A(8)$, $B(0)$. Person $C$ shook $7$ hands, they can't shake $B$'s $A$'s or their own hand, but they shake everyone else's. Hence everyone else now has at least two handshakes except for $C$'s spouse. So $C$'s spouse, $D$, has $1$ handshake. In this manner we can see the rest $6$,$2$ $5$,$3$ and finally Kevin and his spouse: $4$,$4$.

When I first read the problem, I assumed that people didn't know anyone besides their respective spouses, so we have $5$ couples, $4$ possible shakes per $2$ couples, hence $(5*4)*4 / 2$ total handshakes. Now this assumption was wrong, but look at this: $8 * 9 / 2 = 36$ and $40 - 36 = 4$. Exactly the right answer for Kevin's handshakes. Now if $40$ handshakes are distributed among $5$ couples, each one does $8$ shakes, and if we break them evenly among the two people, each does $4$ shakes. So if every person shook hands $4$ times we would have a total of $40$ shakes. Now we notice that there is a pattern to the shakes $(8,0)$, $(7,1)$, $(6,2)$ ... they can all be redistributed to be $(4,4)$, $(4,4)$, $(4,4)$ and would thus produce the same sum of handshakes, so just by intuition the only pair missing is $(4,4)$. Sorry, there is a mess of things going through my head right now trying to sort all these ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Mike, will make sure to format properly.

Comment: This question seems ill-posed. If each person shakes the hand of a person they don't know, how did one person not shake any hands? It should probably be "each person shakes the hands of everyone they don't know". As for the rest, you seem to be going off on a tangent. Is there something about the reasoning in the solution you don't understand?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the solution, but if A shakes 8 hands with 8 people, then C was one of those.  Therefore, C did shake hands with A - and so did everyone else except for A and A's spouse.  And what information is given about Kevin?  Kevin might have shaken hand with any number of people?

Comment: @PerryElliott-Iverson the solution makes perfect sense. I just thought the outcome of my tangent might have deeper reasons for being correct, rather than just a mere coincidence.